# Different Table Row count when executing two queries in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I try to find all table row count in my mysql db. While I executing query below shown

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDb' 
ORDER BY `TABLES`.`TABLE_ROWS`  DESC;
```

I get the output tables and its row count. eg content_data : 200150, 
But when I check each table individually  by using

`select count(*) from content_data`

I get the exact row count ie 219366. What the exact query for finding all row count of tables in mysql ?

Comment: The same question with the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796623/mysql-gives-fluctuating-row-count-when-i-query-schema

Answer (score 1):

count by information_schema.tables or show table status provide approx. count but not exact count, for exact count you have to execute query on db as per below-

```
select count(*) from mydb.mytable;
```

If you want all db tables count then you can create a stored procedure and insert all tables row count in a temp table and then get from that table.