# Why does information_schema.tables give such an unstable answer for number of rows?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I run into a strange problem using MySQL 5.5. I wanted to gather statistics about table size. So, I made up the following query:

```
SELECT table_name AS name, data_length, index_length, table_rows, avg_row_length
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "<MySchema>"
 AND table_name in (<Table names I'm interested in>)
order by table_name;
```

However, I noticed something strange, when I ran this query several times in a few seconds. The data_length and index_length remain actually the same in all queries (or change a little bit, since there were some writes during my script execution made by customers).

However, table_rows gives every time a pretty different answer. For example, the first query gives for a table A about a 10000 rows, the second query says it's about 20000 rows, and so on. However, when I run the query like this:

```
select count(*) from TableA;
```

It gives me the same result over and over again. However, not the information schema, for some reason. What could be wrong with the database? Or maybe I just misunderstand the meaning of table_rows in information_schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL gives fluctuating row count when I query schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796623/mysql-gives-fluctuating-row-count-when-i-query-schema)

Answer (score 4):

From **[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html)**

> The **TABLE_ROWS** column is NULL if the table is in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.
>
> For InnoDB tables, the row count is **only a rough estimate** used in SQL
>   optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)

To update this estimation you need to use `ANALYZE TABLE` (keep in mind that the accuracy dependents on `innodb_stats_persistent_sample_page`:

> **[`innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages)**
>
> The number of index pages to sample when estimating cardinality and other statistics for an indexed column, such as those calculated by ANALYZE TABLE. Increasing the value improves the accuracy of index statistics, which can improve the query execution plan, at the expense of increased I/O during the execution of ANALYZE TABLE for an InnoDB table

To get **exact count** you need to use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: But I could rely on data_length and index_length at least? Do I understand correctly that the sum of those columns gives me the actual size of the table I am investigating?

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984 This will give you only estimation because data is sampled see updated

Comment: Suppose I don't run the analyse table. I just want to know the current table size. Will data_length and index_length give me this summary information? Or is it just an estimate too?

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984 This will be always only estimation (accurate less or more). If you need exact number COUNT(*) is the way. I know you want to outsmart SQL to get result faster but INFORMATION_SCHEMA is tradeoff (accuracy for speed)

Comment: I'm not talking about count and the number of rows, I am asking about the size of table in bytes - will data_length+sum_length give me that info?

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984 For table size you can use `data_length/index_length` more info http://webexplorar.com/how-can-i-get-database-table-sizes/

Answer (score -3):

**FOR INNODB:**

You should use `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS.NUM_ROWS` for accurate table row count data, instead of `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_ROWS`.

I.e to fetch a list of tables which contain rows:

```
SELECT name 
FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tablestats 
WHERE name LIKE ("YOUR_DB_SCHEMA_NAME%")
AND num_rows > 0;
```

In my case, there is a requirement to retroactively write integration tests for a legacy system. Based on the current codebase, using proper `PDO` transaction `rollback()` is out of the question...

For a poor man's transaction rollback, I simply select all tables containing data and truncate before/after running tests. This allows cleanup of seeded data and any other dirty tables due to test inserted data.

**FOR MyISAM:**

you should use `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_ROWS` as stated by lad2025

Comment: `INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS`.`NUM_ROWS` is also an estimate. My own testing on this table suggests it returns the same number as  `TABLES`.`TABLE_ROWS`. COUNT(*) seems to be the only reliable way for innodb.

Comment: Ahh ok, in my particular situation we need a count repeatedly before and after each test it seems to work fine. whereas information schema.tables only works for myisam. In our case it seems there is a delay in the update of the table_row count. I wonder if something else is responsible

Comment: Yes, it's a shame, I really wanted this method to check out because it would be incredibly useful. The documentation mentions that the estimate gets updated after each DML operation which might explain your success with this method if you are getting the difference in row counts.