# SELECT COUNT(*)... & SELECT table_name,table_rows ...; Giving different results (row count), can anyone please explain, why?

Tags: mysql, database

I am transferring tables from 1 database(MySQL) to another database(MYSQL). 
To check table data i am counting number of rows in given table(s) but i am getting different row count for same table(s) when I am executing following 2 queries. Can anyone please explain why it is happening? (also i have uploaded screen of query result)

Queries

1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1; (giving result as 134)
```

2.

```
SELECT table_name,table_rows FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='career';(giving result as 171)**
```

[image]

Comment: The second query appears to be counting the number of tables, not the number of records in test1

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about here. The right way to find the number of rows is your first query:

```
Select count(*) from table;
```

`Count(*)` will count all rows even when the whole row is null. That won't be the case though as almost all tables have Primary key and you just added one to your table.

Table_rows will only give rough estimate of the number of rows in your table and that may vary often if you run that query various times.

For more info, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796623/mysql-gives-fluctuating-row-count-when-i-query-schema)

Hope it helps!