# Monitoring mysql table growth using Prometheus + Grafana

Tags: mysql, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I would like to monitor the growth rate of various mysql tables and alert engineers when growth rate deviates using Prometheus + Grafana.

I have tried monitoring using information_schema table_rows but seems like its meant to be just an approximate value and not useful for my use case.

[MySQL gives fluctuating row count when I query schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796623/mysql-gives-fluctuating-row-count-when-i-query-schema)

Are there any other suitable ready-to-use alternatives or do i have to build my custom exporter?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL Exporter](https://github.com/free/sql_exporter) (disclaimer: I am the author) or some similar exporter that will allow you to run arbitrary SQL queries against your DB, in combination with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` query.

Do note however that (as illustrated by the question you link to) that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` queries run in ~10 ms (in that specific case) as compared to ~500 ms for the `SELECT COUNT(*)` ones. YMMV depending on your table size and whatever else, but it may be worth paying attention to. (Especially since it's not only your exporter and Prometheus that have to deal with the latency, but also the DB with the corresponding extra load.)

Comment: thanks Alin. however, im wondering if there's any way to implement a less expensive solution:
- run `select count(*) from table` to get all records for the very first query
- subsequent queries will build off this snapshot and only query count for the current date and add onto snapshot